# How to use libgdx without having a core project?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have been trying to implement libgdx without a core project in a new eclipse project, but I keep getting:

> The method initialize(ApplicationListener,
>   AndroidApplicationConfiguration) in the type AndroidApplication is not
>   applicable for the arguments (AndroidApplication,
>   AndroidApplicationConfiguration)

The code I use is quite simple at the moment:

```
package com.debels.androidapplication;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = false;

        initialize(new AndroidApplication(), cfg);
    }
}
```

and

```
package com.debels.androidapplication;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.FPSLogger;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.debels.androidapplication.screens.MainMenuScreen;

public class AndroidApplication extends Game{
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Texture texture;
    private Sprite sprite;
    private FPSLogger fps;
    @Override
    public void create(){
        float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h/w);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        //texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/libgdx.png"));
        //texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

        //TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

        /*sprite = new Sprite(region);
        sprite.setSize(0.9f, 0.9f * sprite.getHeight() / sprite.getWidth());
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth()/2, sprite.getHeight()/2);
        sprite.setPosition(-sprite.getWidth()/2, -sprite.getHeight()/2);*/
        setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
        fps = new FPSLogger();

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();
        /*fps.log();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        sprite.draw(batch);
        batch.end();*/
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        super.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        super.resume();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you have problems with setting up the initial multi project structure, use the setup gui for it. In my opinion there is no reason to not have a core project.

Comment: Can you please check this question if you can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261140/using-libgdx-without-androidapplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you are sending a (gdx)AndroidApplication instance to the ini instead of a (gdx)AndroidApplicationListener (which is any class that extends Game or implements ApplicationListener).

You get all confused because you named that class AndroidApplication...

Change this:

```
initialize(new AndroidApplication(), cfg);
```

to this:

```
initialize(new com.debels.androidapplication.AndroidApplication(), cfg);
```

Or better yet, change the name of that class.
Also dont forget to copy the gdx.jar to the android project libs folder.

Comment: How could I miss that... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem. And I probably should have said this in the answer, it is better if you keep the core, desktop and android projects separated, because you can quickly test in your computer instead of deploying to a device every time or using the slow emulator.:3

Comment: The only reason why I'm not having a core project is because I can't use android methods such as Bluetooth, I saw a way on stackoverflow about making an interface on the core project, then implementing it on the android project and sending it back to the core project. its just to strange, but like you say I should have a core project in case I want to quickly test or support more platforms, Thanks again :)