# Using LibGdx without AndroidApplication?

Tags: libgdx

In my project, I am interested only in a particular part of LibGDX, that is viewing 3D model and animating it, no inputs or other functionality is needed.

As I need to view 3D models in a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` within a `RecyclerView.Adapter`

As I have searched, I found that I need to get the `view` at `AndroidGraphics` class, ex: `GLSurfaceView`

However, I have no idea how to do the initialization without `AndroidApplication`, would this be possible?

Any idea?

Comment: You can use libGDX within a fragment. Did you try this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a libgdx view in android and add it to your layout. Here's how:

```
AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new 
AndroidApplicationConfiguration();

View gameView = initializeForView(new Game(this), config); // Game is your libgdx Mainclass 

layout = new RelativeLayout(this); // or your custom layout
layout.addView(gameView);
setContentView(layout);
```